# How does maxDepth parameter in copyFromRealm method affects performance?

Tags: android, performance, realm, query-performance

I have a object A which contains list of objects of type B which contains list of objects of type C. This is the deepest level of hierarchy. Now, when I do where() query I need to have all these data as a result (meaning, objects A which contains objects B, which contains objects C ). The ***"problem"*** is that I need a list of unmanaged objects.

So, my question is: if I want to fetch all these data, are there any differences in fetching speed when I provide `maxDepth` parameter or not to `copyFromRealm` method, since I need this for the deepest possible depth in hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `maxDepth` value, Realm will provide `null` values beyond the given `maxDepth` level. So, if you are fine with `null` values, setting `maxDepth` will be faster, because Realm sets `null` and not the actual value. In case you are not OK with `null` value, and set the `maxDepth` as the maximum possible depth as per your code, it will have same performance.

Performance wise there is no difference; if you use `copyFromRealm` with or without `maxDepth` parameter, because in case you don't provide a `maxDepth` value, Realm sets it as `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and calls `copyFromRealm` method like following,

```
public <E extends RealmModel> List<E> copyFromRealm(Iterable<E> realmObjects) {
    return copyFromRealm(realmObjects, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

So, in both the cases, you call the same function.

**TL;DR** - If your `maxDepth` is 3(A->B->C) and you set `maxDepth` as 3, there is no performance difference, if you set `maxDepth` as `0 < maxDepth < 3` then yes its faster, but you get `null` values beyond the `maxDepth`.